# Check status of dialog in android

Tags: android

I create dialog by:

```
protected void showAlertDialog(String title, String message) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new Builder(this);
    if(title != null) {
        builder.setTitle(title);
    }
    if(message != null) {
        builder.setMessage(message);
    }
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            backToMainActivity();
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}
```

and after that I use it in my activity. How can I check status my dialog. I mean I want to check when dialog was canceled or closed. This is any way to do that? I have a example when user click backbutton and dialog was closed and I want finish activity when dialog was closed. This is any way to check if dialog is showing or was closed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may just add cancel button to your dialog:

```
builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new OnClickListener() {

@Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            //Your code here
        }
    });
```

If you want dialog with ok button only you may else using such methods as - setOnCancelListener, setOnDissmisListener on your builder.

Answer (score 2):

You can check

`if (dialog.isShowing())`

it should be what you need

Comment: yes, but how can I use it in activity when I have this method?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean

Comment: I am using this method to show dialog. I have no field dialog in activity to check in your way.

Comment: you have to save an instance of your Dialog as class variable and check its value when you need. It is the only way

Answer (score 2):

You could use this piece of code:

```
builder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Activity.finish();
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the `isShowing()` method is not included in the `AlertDialog.Builder` class, however the `Dialog` class includes `isShowing();`

An `AlertDialog.Builder` is used to create an `AlertDialog`. Once you have this instance of an `AlertDialog`, **you can determine whether or not it is still showing by then calling isShowing() on it.**